# Why a blank image is displaying at the start of jquery slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using the source code of a webpage to add the slider on my website. However, the first image of the slider is shown to be blank. Currently, there are five images in my slider. However, before the slider, there is always shown to be the blank image. I tried alot, and debug the code using google inspect element option, but I cannot figure out the problem.

```css
section#hero {
 height: 395px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #d9dadb;
 background: #fff;
 clear: both;
}
div.page {
 min-height: 400px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}
div#hero {
 width: 980px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 height: 395px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
 div #hero .cycle-slideshow,
 div#hero div.slider-image {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
 }
 
 .bannerimage {
  width: 294px;
  padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Marvel Tech</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
            </head>
<body>

           <!–– Slider Section >
<section id="hero">

 <div id="hero" style="position:relative;">
  <div id="slider-prev">
   <img src="images/slide_left.png" alt="Previous Slide">
  </div>
      <!–– First Image >
  <div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-timeout="5000" data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle-prev="#slider-prev" data-cycle-next="#slider-next" style="position: relative
  ; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="slider-image cycle-slide cycle-sentinel" style="clear: both; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 1; display: block; visibility: hidden;">
     <div style="width: auto; position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 70; visibility: hidden;">
      <a href="/services/turbomachinery-design" style="visibility: hidden;"><img src="images/turbine_hero001c.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;"></a>
     </div></div>
     
           <!–– Second Image >
   <div class="slider-image cycle-slide" style="clear: both; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 96; visibility: hidden; opacity: 1; display: block;">
     <div style="width: auto;position: static; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 70;">
      <a href=""><img src="images/turbine_hero001a.jpg"></a>
     </div>
          </div>
  <!–– Third Image >
   <div class="slider-image cycle-slide cycle-slide-active" style="clear: both; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 99; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; display: block;">
     <div style="width: auto;position: static; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 70;">
      <a href=""><img src="images/turbine_hero001d.jpg"></a>
     </div>
     </div>
   <div class="slider-image cycle-slide" style="clear: both; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 97; visibility: hidden; opacity: 1; display: block;">
     <div style="width: auto;position: static; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 70;">
      <a href=""><img src="images/hero_01a.jpg"></a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider-image cycle-slide" style="clear: both; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 96; visibility: hidden; opacity: 1; display: block;">
     <div style="width: auto;position: static; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 70;">
      <a href=""><img src="images/sg35f.JPG"></a>
     </div>
    </div>
  <div id="slider-next">
   <img src="images/slide_right.png" alt="Next Slide">
  </div>
 </div>
</section>

                    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script type='text/javascript' src='a6ecd37.js'></script>
                
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your file path you have given like images/turbine_hero001c.jpg and check also file existence

Comment: @Maheskumar I have cross checked it. the file path is correct and image also exists.

Comment: Okay @sridraaleem, first of all access your image file through browser lets say: https://stackoverflow.com/images/turbine_hero001c.jpg if its loaded means just that path to img src otherwise your given path wrong

Comment: @Maheskumar yes it's working now. there was a problem with the first image. I was using it twice. Thank you

Comment: Okay @sridraaleem, superb